# ORM Database design for quiz website

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, orm

I am trying to learn ORM and better structuring a database. I am working on a simply quiz web app to try to learn the relationships between tables. Am I on the right track here?

Down below are my tables. And I was thinking like this:

- Question has one answer.
- Answer belongs to many questions.
- Question has many alternatives.
- Alternatives belongs to many
  questions.

---

### The tables

**Question**

- ID
- Question

---

**Answer**

- ID
- Answer

---

**Alternatives**

- ID
- Alternative

---

**QuestionAlternative**

- QuestionID
- AlternativeID

Comment: I think you've got too many tables. question and answer would suffice - with a column in answer to tell us to which question it relates, and another to tell us if it's right

Comment: In QuestionAlternatives there would be a column for "Correct" or similar fashion you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a data model something like this:

[image: ERD]

You have a list of questions, each of which has zero, one or more offered options (possible answers).  For each question, a user enters an answer.  This answer may refer to a specific `OPTION` if applicable, or it could contain some kind of free-form information in the `ANSWER` table itself.